# Почему не выводится значение из input при клике по кнопке (React, Hooks)?

Tags: reactjs

Здесь в коде

```
export default function InputComponent(props) {
  const [newLink, setNewLink] = useState('');
    const handleClick = (e) => {
          //console.log('setNewLink');
          console.log(setNewLink(e.target.value));
          const insertValue = setNewLink(e.target.value);
          insertValue.innerHTML = "<p></p>";
        };
    return (
    <div>          
        <InputField value={newLink} onChange={(e) => setNewLink(e.target.value)}/>
        <ButtonsWrapper>
        <Btn text="Add +" background="#636663" type = "button" onClick={handleClick}></Btn>
          <Btn text = "Generate" background="#48ED39" width = "180px"></Btn>
        </ButtonsWrapper>
        <React.Fragment>
    {/*{insertValue}*/}
        </React.Fragment>        
    </div>
  );
}
```

В итоге - не выводится даже в консоль значение из инпута

```
console.log(setNewLink(e.target.value));
```

Как должно работать:
значение которое получаем из инпута

```
<InputField value={newLink} onChange={(e) => setNewLink(e.target.value)}/>
```

при клике по кнопке `<Btn text="Add +"`
должно выводиться здесь

```
 <React.Fragment>
       {insertValue}
    </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

newLink - текущее состояние, setNewLink - функция, которое обновляет это состояние

```
const [newLink, setNewLink] = useState('');
```

Поэтому не очень понятно, что вы пытаетесь здесь сделать:

```
const insertValue = setNewLink(e.target.value);
insertValue.innerHTML = "<p></p>";
```

В методе `onChange={(e) => setNewLink(e.target.value)}` вы уже обновляете значение newLink. Поэтому при нажатии на кнопку вам будет достаточно просто отобразить это значение на экране.

**Быстрое решение.** Можно добавить переменную, которая будет отвечать за отображение/нет сообщения на экране.

```
const [newLink, setNewLink] = useState('');
const [isDisplayed, setDisplay] = useState(false); // сперва ничего не отображаем - false
```

Тогда при клике на кнопку, мы просто меняем значение новой переменной

```
const handleClick = () => {
  setDisplay(!isDisplayed); // меняем значение на противоположное
};
```

И при рендеринге смотрим значение, в случае чего - выводим на экран

```
 <React.Fragment>
   {isDisplayed ? newLink : ''}
 </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответы, но здесь вообще стало непонятно - "при нажатии на кнопку вам будет достаточно просто отобразить это значение на экране."   Разве я не отображаю на экране, добавив на клик работу функции Хендлклик? Почему например вот это onChange={(e) => setNewLink(e.target.value)}   если повесить на Submit - работало, а если на клик - то в консоль не выводит. Если в Хендлклик прописать работу функции а на кнопку повесить ее вызов - то почему-т не работает....

Comment: "Поэтому не очень понятно, что вы пытаетесь здесь сделать:

const insertValue = setNewLink(e.target.value);
insertValue.innerHTML = "<p></p>";"    -   добавить в тег <p> значение из поля ввода.   Но пока что не принципиально. Главное для начала чтобы хотябы в консоль выводилось это значение

Comment: @Lena, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, а без поверки "const handleClick = () => {
  setDisplay(!isDisplayed); " - нельзя обойтись?   а как например в случае, если надо поочередно выводить разные значения при каждом клике? (если цикл добавить). Или в Реакте - обязательно в любом случае нужна эта проверка поля?

Comment: @Lena, это не проверка. В setDisplay(!isDisplayed); вы меняете значение isDisplayed на противоположное.  Т.е. если было isDisplayed=false, то станет isDisplayed=true и наоборот

Answer (score 0):

При клике по кнопке `e.target` - это сама кнопка, никакого `value` у неё нет.

Comment: Можно подробнее? Ведь в Хендлклик добавлено const insertValue = setNewLink(e.target.value); - то есть взять значение из инпута.  То есть value - не у кнопки, а у инпута.

Comment: @Lena, при нажатии на кнопку, у вас срабатывает handleClick = (e). Далее вы пытаетесь вызывать setNewLink(e.target.value);, где е - тип события (у вас click), target - элемент, на котором сработал обработчик (в данном случае button) и как вам уже сказали, никакого value у кнопки нет